# How to find process which uses most bandwidth

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, bandwidth

How can I find the process which uses most bandwidth on a Linux PC?

With `iftop` it's possible to find which connections produce most bandwidth, but how to find the process?

Answer (score 6):

nethogs is something similar, but shows also the process (http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I totally could of used this about eight hours ago!

Answer (score 3):

little clumsy solution, but

start

`iftop -nNP`

and after it starts, press `'t'` and now you need to pause by pressing `'P' (shift+p)`.
copy the desired `'IP:port'` from 2nd column and start as super-user

```
netstat -tnp | grep "<paste_IP:port_here>"
```

and at the last field of the output you should see PID/program.
hope this help.